# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying @> point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app and am running this query:

`partner_found = Partner.find_by("partners.geo_polygon @> point '(:lat,:lng)'", lat: latitude, lng: longitude)`

In my dev environment this runs fine, but in test it throws an error:

`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying @> point`

Both my dev and test environments are running Postgres databases. What am I missing?

edit: More info, my test database created the geo_polygon columns as `character varying` while it is correctly `polygon` in the development database.

Comment: I guess you are missing postgres hstore in test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rahul! The test database was missing hstore. I turned it on is psql with `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;`

I also added to my migration: `enable_extension "hstore"`

Also I found these answers at http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails